# How can I print the content of my TabControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I would like to iterate through all tabs and print the content.

**How can I print the content of my TabControl?**

I have tried using FlowDocument. The problem is that the half of the page width gets printed.

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried using a [System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.printdialog.aspx)? Check out its [PrintVisual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.printdialog.printvisual.aspx) method.

Comment: Yes, I don't want to use PrintVisual. Since the content is out of the screen.